# how to select last row in TGrid on the click of a button

Tags: delphi, pascal

how does one select the last row in a TGrid when the user clicks on a button? I have a table which is filtered by date and I have a start date and end date button. When the user clicks them I need it to select the specific row.

Comment: What about table.Last?

Comment: table being the grids name ? i tried that it didnt work

Comment: @UweRaabe I used invoicesGrid.SelectRow(0); to select the first one but invoicesGrid.SelectRow(-1 ); eont select the last one for some reason

Comment: `invoicesGrid.SelectRow(invoicesGrid.RowCount-1);`

Comment: I assume with *table* you mean a TDataSet, which provides the *Last* method. If *table* is not a TDataSet just ignore my comment.

Comment: ¿Are you appliying the filter to the Dataset or to the grid directly (like DevExpress for example)?

Answer (score 1):

```
invoicesGrid.SelectRow(invoicesGrid.RowCount-1);
```